# Conditional formatting, color as many cells as the number above

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

i need to color as many cells as the number in the cell above. For example in the cell A1 i have the number 4 and i need to color 4 cells below that A2, A3, A4 and A5.
[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried -- even if it is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming row 1 has the number of cells to color, in cell A2, create a conditional format with the formula `=A$1>=ROW()-1`.  Copy this format to the entire table.

[image]